# Where can I find Squirt's Necklace?

Tags: diablo-iii

While experimenting at the Auction House, I noticed that there were several copies of a particular Legendary necklace, called "Squirt's Necklace," for sale for crazy prices.  I know that Squirt is a merchant in the Bazaar during Act 2, but I didn't see her selling this item, and she heavily implies that she would *hurt* me if I was to try to take it from her directly.

It's a level 24 necklace from what I understand, so it would work well with my mid-to-late 20's Witch Doctor.  However, the prices for this item on the AH are *crazy high*.

Is there any reliable way to get this item?  Does it drop from some particular boss or mob?   Does Squirt sell it under certain circumstances?  Or am I just supposed to get lucky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Squirt's Necklace](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/squirts-necklace) is nothing special, just one of the low-level legendary items.

It's so expensive because it's so rare, nothing more.

Comment: You still don't say if it is a drop or if you buy it....

Comment: @Lyrion It's a legendary. There's an open question elsewhere about whether or not legendaries ever show up on vendors.

Comment: True i've read that one, but maybe not everyone that is using this site? Aswell as it might be a crafted item...

Comment: Sad days.  It's too bad these low level legendary items are so rare.  My current necklace is "teh suxorz"